# Memory leak caused by incomplete executeAsync() function execution

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow.js

As the title suggests, I was inferring using `executeAsync()` for an object detection task. The function works well when I have a detection continuously in my live video and there's no memory leak. However, if I have no detection in one particular frame, there will be an error while it executes the `executeAsync()` function.

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

And here's the memory leak that happened when there's no detection.

> {unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 422861990, numTensors: 1111, numDataBuffers: 673, numBytes: 320663096}
>
> {unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 490830799, numTensors: 1263, numDataBuffers: 752, numBytes: 371606568}
>
> {unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 558799608, numTensors: 1415, numDataBuffers: 831, numBytes: 422550040}

I am thinking the issue lies in the dangling tensors that are created in `executeAsync()` since if there's a detection I would dispose the tensors, but if there's no detection, I couldn't get a reference of the dangling tensors since the `test_result` variable hasn't been created yet due to the aforementioned error.

I wanted to use `tf.tidy()` but I did some research on it and apparently it can't be used with asynchronous functions.

How can I eradicate the memory leak? Or is there a problem with my model inference? Really appreciate any help.

```js
async detect(video){
    console.log("detecting...");

    var example = tf.browser.fromPixels(video);
    var tf4d = example.expandDims(0);

    try{
        // error if there's no detection
        const test_result = await this.model.executeAsync({ image_tensor: tf4d }, ['detection_boxes', 'num_detections', 'detection_classes', 'detection_scores']) as tf.Tensor[];
        
        this.no_detection = false;
        var detection_boxes = test_result[0].dataSync();
        var num_detections = test_result[1].dataSync();
        var detection_classes = test_result[2].dataSync();
        var detection_scores = test_result[3].dataSync();

        // dispose tensors to avoid memory leak
        await Promise.all(test_result.map(t => t.data()));
        test_result.map(t => t.dispose());
        tf.dispose(test_result);

        tf4d.dispose();
        example.dispose();

        console.log(tf.memory());

    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("No detection");
        console.log(error)
        this.no_detection = true;
        // dispose of tensor created from images if theres no detection
        tf4d.dispose();
        example.dispose();
        console.log(tf.memory());
        
    }

}
```

Edited: I think it's also worth mentioning that I retrained my own model using the Tensorflow Object Detection API following this [tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-inference-graph).

I think there might also be some problem with the exporting of inference graph using `export_inference_graph.pb` since I also got this

> 23 ops no flops stats due to incomplete shapes.
>   while converting.

I tried converting from a pretrained inference graph to a tfjs model and it works fine - if there's no detection `executeAsync()` would just return an empty array.

That's the reason why I think maybe there's a problem with the exporting of inference graph of my own model..?

Here's the command (I tried both with and without the `--input_shape` argument):

`python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --input_shape 1,300,300,3 --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v2.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-38153 --output_directory trained-inference-graphs/output_inference_graph`